# Problem with R code for spectral clustering

Tags: r, clustering

am writing a simple R script to test the spectral clustering algorithm but for the eigenvalues I don't get them all positive and lambda0 is different from 0. here is my script

```
Dsqrt<-matrix(0,length(V(g)),length(V(g)))  # The D^-0.5 matrix
   for(i in 1:(length(V(g))-1))
         Dsqrt[i,i]<-1/sqrt(degree(g,V(g)[i-1]))        

   L<-graph.laplacian(g, normalized=TRUE) #Here L[i,i]=1 and L[i,j]= 1/sqrt(d[i]*d[j])
   L<-Dsqrt %*% L %*% Dsqrt  
   Eigns<-eigen(L)
```

And when I check `Eigns$values` sometimes I get some negative values.

Can any one point me my error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **First guess**: You're a C/C++/Java programmer used to zero-indexing. Matrices in $R$ aren't zero-indexed, but rather one-indexed. Also, you use the call `V(g)[i-1]` which the first time through the loop is `V(g)[-1]` and the second time is `V(g)[0]`, neither of which, I'm guessing, are what you actually intend to do.

Comment: Also, your call `graph.laplacian(g, normalized=TRUE)` returns the normalized graph Laplacian. In other words, if $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the degrees and $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then `graph.laplacian(g, normalized=TRUE)` returns $I - D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$. You appear to be multiplying on the right and left by $D^{-1/2}$ again, which would yield $D^{-1} - D^{-1} A D^{-1}$. Is that *really* what you mean to calculate?

Comment: @cardinal even if I try only the `graph.laplacian` I get almost the same results. Here the laplacian is  D-A, if it is normalized we will have 1 in the diagonal and `1/(sqrt(d[i])*sqrt(d[j])` for the other edges. Here I want to to do  D^1/2 * (D-A) * D^1/2

Comment: Read the documentation carefully. There is a minus sign in front of `1/(sort(d[i])*sqrt(d[j]))`, from this it is clear that `graph.laplacian(g, normalized=TRUE)` already returns your desired quantity. You don't need to do any additional construction of `Dsqrt` or the `for`-loop, etc.

Comment: And, somehow, the first `sqrt` became `sort` above. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still the same the problem, I think it is an approximation problem because all the negative values have at leat 9 zero after the period.

Comment: Are you now just doing `L <- graph.laplacian(g, normalized=TRUE); eigen(L)$values` ? What is the size of $L$? Based on your description, it's quite possible it's some sort of numerical instability. Note that you're guaranteed to have at least one zero eigenvalue since $D^{1/2} \mathbf{1}$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue of zero.